Why does FullSimplify crash the kernel?
Bug introduced in 13.2 or earlier and fixed in 14.1
Save your work before attempting.
I realise this may get fixed in later versions – I am more interested in the why.
On OSX 14.4 and Mathematica 13.2 the code below will crash the kernel if FullSimplify is uncommented.
Block[{α0, β0, ϵ, γ,  δ, θ}, 
 1/8 α0 (8 + 4 ϵ Sin[θ]^2 + 
    4 (δ + (δ - ϵ) Cos[2 θ]) Sin[θ]^2 - (8 α0^2 (δ - ϵ) * 
  Cos[θ]^2 (δ + ϵ + (δ - ϵ) Cos[2 θ]) Sin[θ]^4)/(α0^2 - β0^2) - 
 (δ + ϵ + (δ - ϵ) Cos[2 θ])^2 Sin[θ]^4)(*//FullSimplify*)
]

If I evaluate the expression and run something like %//FullSimplify after, it just runs endlessly.
What is more bizarre is I could swear this code was working (with the FullSimplify!) a few weeks ago but my time machine is broken and can no longer verify this statement...
Marking this as a bug since I got independent confirmation this is not to do with my setup. Either way, if someone can offer some plausible reason why this happens I would really appreciate it. This has been reported to Wolfram Research.
---EDIT---
Since first posting, this has been confirmed by WR tech support and carries on to v14 on Mac and Windows.

I can confirm the crash happening also in 14.0.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (December 13, 2023). As usual – kernel crash is something that certainly isn't supposed to happen, so you should report this to the technical support.

Thanks, justified to mark with bugs tag

With v14 on a Mac, it doesn't crash if you use // TrigToExp // FullSimplify; however, you end up with a higher LeafCount than when you started.

@BobHanlon yeah, same with //TrigExpand //FullSimplify doesn't crash but higher LeafCount

It crashes even on a simpler expression that is a part of the original expression 8 + 4 d Sin[e]^2 +    4 (c + (c - d) Cos[2 e]) Sin[     e]^2 - (c + d + (c - d) Cos[2 e])^2 Sin[e]^4 // FullSimplify.

A more simpler one (a-b) Cos[2 x]+(a+b+(a-b) Cos[2 x])^2 Sin[x]^2. Using the option Trig->True it won't crash

The above, replacing // FullSimplify[#, Trig -> True] & crashes just the same

I am voting to close this question, since you already got the confirmation and the answer from the WRI – the kernel crashes because there is something wrong in the kernel code.

@Domen yep, agreed
